# __webpack_require__(...) is not a function + Angular 2

Tags: angular, webpack

I am using angular 2 & getting this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...) is not a function`

for this line:

`styles: [String(require('../../../static/v4/angular/scss/app.scss'))],`

Comment: Are you processing the css with a loader? Can you show that? (If not, webpack is probably generating a file incorrectly.)

Comment: here is the loader: `{ test: /\.scss$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'}`

Comment: @DheerajAgrawal Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Kevin yes I did, but don't remember how, probably I had added resolve object on me webpack config like this: ```resolve: {
    root: [ path.join(__dirname, 'src') ],
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.css', '.scss']
  },```